# Check All rows are identical

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have to check all the rows are identical or not.

My Example:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |
```

Is there any function to do this directly, without running any kind of loop

I can do this using loop, but want to know whether there is a better way without using column name

Comment: Why would you have identical rows?

Comment: I have to check copy stuff

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam, if any (or both) of the answers helped and was the solution to your question please mark as solution(s). Cheers!

Comment: Actually It didn't, because my case was without using column name.

Answer (score 2):

You could count the number of distinct combinations. If it's more than one, not all rows are identical:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a function. Yet, no looping mechanism should be involved. Instead, you could run a select statement where you group based on all the columns then get the count of all groups:

```
select count(s.cntAll)
from (
     select count(*) as cntAll
     from yourTable
     group by column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6
) s
```

If the count(s.cntAll) = 1 then you validate the rows being all the same.